# SWIFT: inputString.componentsSeparatedBy generating Int Array?

Tags: arrays, swift

There is the function

```
var array = inputString.componentsSeparatedByString("\r")
```

for creating a string array from a string. Is there any chance to convert an element of the array before inserting, so I get an array of Int instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
let array = inputString.componentsSeparatedByString("\r").map{$0.toInt()!}
```

or using the native Swift function `split`

```
let array = (split(inputString, isSeparator: {$0 == "\r"})).map{$0.toInt()!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `String` array and then use `map` to convert each element to an `Int`.